Using git to deploy and pushing updates to Laravel production site
I guess a similar question has been asked before more than once, but I still hope it's OK to post it here. I have found a lot of information by googling, but not exactly what I am looking for. Some examples uses GitLab actions or third party solutions to deploy/updating the site. I haven't found a good description/tutorial on how to use "pure" git.
This is my setup:

Local environment running Herd and using PhpStorm.
External server with ssh-access.

This is what I have done so far:

Created a local git-repo in PhpStorm and made an initial commit.
Added my remote server in PhpStorm.
On the remote server I have created an empty folder called site.git, and inside this folder I have ran git init --bare.
From PhpStorm I have pushed my local master to the external server.
On my external server I have created a folder called site and inside it I first ran git clone ~/site.git . which give me all the files from my local repo (except those in .gitignore).
Then on my external server I ran the following:

composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache

I also added the .env-file with the correct settings for mail/db and other stuff (actually did this before running php artisan config:cache).
I got the site up and running. When making changes I edit my changes in PhpStorm, committing them to my local repo and then pushing it to my external server. Then on the external server I cd to my site and run git pull. This usually work, but sometimes the server has added some files, user uploaded and log files and other stuff which I forgot to add to .gitignore, which requires a lot fiddling with git on the server to exclude them.
Now I have a few questions regarding all this:

Is this the proper way of using git for deploying/updating a live site?
Can I add some kind of hook on the external server so it automatically run git pull (or whatever command is proper) when a push has been made to it?
Is git pull the correct git-command to use? Should I maybe use git fetch instead? Should I run git reset --hard before every pull?
Is there a way to ignore changes made in the repo on my external server (so I don't have to care about adding stuff to .gitignore, that the webserver might have added/modified). I will never edit anything in my project on the server, the truth will always be in my local repo, so I don't want any conflicts when running git pull on the external server, I just want it to sync with my local repo.


Check out https://github.com/levizoesch/laravel-web-deploy I also have some helper commands, tools in my github that may help you.

You might find the Deploy for Commits plugin useful.
